# Generic object needs a cast even though it implements the required interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

Don't think the title can explain what i'm on about and it's a bit difficult to explain, so i'll let the code do the talking.  You can copy+paste this into LINQPad and run it as a C# program, or make the necessary adjustments as a regular c# project in visual studio (e.g.: change calls to Dump() to Console.Writeline() etc.) -

Note that if you uncomment out the line in the doStuff method, it won't compile.

My question is, why do i need the cast when generic2 already implements `Iab<TA,TB>`?  Is this some covariance thing?  I'm still on .NET 3.5.

```
void Main()
{
    doStuff<a,b>();
}

public void doStuff<TA, TB>()
where TA : class, Ia, new()
where TB : class, Ib, new()
{
    Iab<TA, TB> x = null;

    x = new generic1<TA, TB>();
    x.Go().Dump();

    //x = new generic2<TA>(); // <-Cannot implicitly convert type 'UserQuery.generic2<TA>' to 'UserQuery.Iab<TA,TB>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
    x = (Iab<TA, TB>) new generic2<TA>();
    x.Go().Dump();
}

public interface Ia
{}

public interface Ib
{}

public class a : Ia
{}

public class b : Ib
{}

public interface Iab<TA,TB>
where TA : class, Ia, new()
where TB : class, Ib, new()
{
    string Go();
}

public class generic1<TA, TB> : Iab<TA,TB>
where TA : class, Ia, new()
where TB : class, Ib, new()
{
    public string Go()
    {
        return "generic Base called";
    }
}

public class generic2<TA> : Iab<TA,b>
where TA : class, Ia, new()
{
public string Go()
    {
        return "generic Sub called";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is because you will always get that error when one or more of the types (in this case, `TS`) is not known at compile time.

The compiler can't guarantee that `doStuff()` will be called with compatible types, so it forces you to cast.

To see why the compiler can't do this, try calling `doStuff()` as follows:

```
public class X: b {}

...

doStuff<a, X>(); // Compiles ok but:
```

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'generic2`1[Demo.Program+X]' to type 'Iab`2[Demo.Program+X,Demo.Program+Y]'.

So it is possible for you to call it with types that will make it crash; the compiler won't silently let you do that.